# Boost log autoflush does not work for files

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I'm using boost 1.63 for logging with the following line of code to use Boost config file for logging:

```
Logger::initFromConfig(logConfigName);
```

I decided so because I want it to be configurable and this way I could save myself from understanding Boost log setup API. Config file contents are:

```
[Core]
DisableLogging="false"

[Sinks.SYSLF]
Destination="TextFile"
Asynchronous="true"
AutoFlush="true"
Format="[%TimeStamp(format=\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f\")%][%Severity%] %Message%"
Target="logs"
FileName="dsmip_%N.log"
RotationTimePoint="00:00:00"
ScanForFiles="Matching"
MaxSize="10000000"
Filter="%Severity% >= info"

[Sinks.Console]
Destination="Console"
AutoFlush="true"
Format="[%TimeStamp(format=\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f\")%][%Severity%] %Message%"
Filter="%Severity% >= debug"
```

My problem is autoflush does not work for files. On stdout I get every event instantly, but the files are written first when I exit the application. This is quite embarassing for logging...

First I used 1.58, the situation was the same. What do I do wrong?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards: Balazs Bamer

Comment: It's difficult to suggest anything since you haven't shown any code. Boost.Log does support `AutoFlush` parameter for the test file sink, and as far as I can see, it is set correctly. One idea I have is that your application exits quickly, and since the sink is async (due to `Asynchronous` set to true) the dedicated processing record thread does not manage to process log records before the process exits, at which point the queued records are flushed. If you really want your records in the file ASAP, you should avoid async logging.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention the small [class](https://github.com/oci-labs/BoostLog/) I use for log initialization. All I use from it is initializing log from config file.
However, my program has been running for hours, and had plenty of time logging everything. I solve exiting by catching SIGTERM and SIGINT, and during shutdown even the last event gets logged.
I have also tried setting RotationInterval to 1 min. This way I get completed logfiles even during runtime. Setting it to 1 hour would be a manageable workaround, although no real solution.

Answer (score 2):

Google was my friend, I have found the solution [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2014/03/81610.php). Boost really operates such that it creates the log file in the application directory, and only copies it to the destination when it is closed (log rotates or the program exists). So, in order to get all the log files appear in a specific directory, one has to include the directory name in the filename pattern **as well as** in the target.

```
[Sinks.SYSLF]
...
Target="logs"
FileName="logs/dsmip_%N.log"
```

Best regards: Balazs